# Laravel 9 Inertia pagination

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-9, inertiajs, laravel-pagination

I have the order function, in which it shows the items related to said order, what I want to do is, paginate only the items within the order.

```
public function order()
{
    $orderId = request()->get('id', 0);
    $order = null;
    $order = OrderItem::with(['items'])->find($orderId);

    if ($orderId != 0) {
        if ($order == null) {
            return Inertia::render('IDashboard/utils/IError');
        }
    }

    return Inertia::render(
        'Orders/IData',
        ['order' => $order]
    );
}
```

I have tried with:

```
public function order()
{
    $orderId = request()->get('id', 0);
    $order = null;
    $order = OrderItem::find($orderId);

    if ($orderId != 0) {
        if ($order == null) {
            return Inertia::render('IDashboard/utils/IError');
        }
    }

    $items = Item::where('order_item_id', $orderId)->paginate(10);

    return Inertia::render(
        'Orders/IData',
        ['order' => $order, 'itemsList' => $items]
    );
}
```

But the problem in this other case is that, when doing the pagination in the Vue component, and hitting page 2, it does not show me any information. Child component.

```
props: {
    is: Function,
    order: Object,
    orderItems: Object,
    itemsList: Object,
},
<IItemCalculate
   v-for="(
       item, index
       ) in orderItems"
       :order="order"
       :item="item"
       :key="index"/>
<IPagination :links="itemsList.links" /> //general pagination component:
```

the path i am using is:

```
Route::get('/order', 'App\Http\Controllers\ItemController@order')->name('order');
```

Errores.
The error is that, at the moment of giving page 2, or next, the content is not displayed, or The error is that, at the moment of giving page 2, or next, the content is not displayed, or when I do the pagination within the relationship, that is `$items = $order->items()->paginate(10)`, throws the error, member function items() on null, also when going to the next page.

Thank you very much, I'm up to date.

Comment: Do you have an error ?

Comment: What does your url looks like in page 1 ?

Comment: I have already updated the body of my question, the route looks like this:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/order?id=1

Comment: Then in page 2 the  `id=1` will be gone and replace by `page=2` ?

Comment: yes exactly, that is the problem, order?page=2, and looking at the vue props, both the items and the order data are lost, I have tried to make a method with inertia, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by including the `order_id` in the path instead of query like : `127.0.0.1:8000/order/1` then modify the controller a little.

```
Route::get('order/{id}', [...])->name('orders');
```

Since you want to render different page in case the `order` do not exists you can skip the `Route-Model Binding`.

```
public function order($id) {
    
    $order = Order::query()->find($id);
    
    if(is_null($order)) {
        return Inertia::render('IDashboard/utils/IError');
    }

    $items = Item::query()
                ->where('order_item_id', $order->id)
                ->paginate(10);

    return Inertia::render('Orders/IData', compact('order','items'));

}
```

If you really want to include the `order_id` as a query string you can look into this. I didn't try it yet.

[Appending Query String Values in Pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/pagination#appending-query-string-values)

Comment: Hello, good evening. I appreciate your answer. It was very useful to me. If I wanted to make a query, however, I left it in another OnlyOrder function. Making that change or addition, it works great, many thanks again.